# Can I copy a Boot Camp partition (on an external drive) into a VMWare image?

Tags: mac-osx, image, bootcamp

I have an old hard drive that used to be in my MacBook Pro that has a Boot Camp partition. When I upgraded the hard drive in my MBP, I didn't copy over the Boot Camp partition. Now I want to use the old hard drive for something else, but don't want to lose the Boot Camp partition. Can I copy it into a VMWare image (Fusion) or otherwise copy it into some other kind of file? (It's only a 15G partition, small but not small enough to fit on a DVD).

Answer (score 2):

You can dd it to an archive.
Unmount all partitions on that drive or boot using live cd ([SystemRescueCd](http://www.sysresccd.org/Main_Page) for example) and do something like:

```
dd if=/dev/hda | gzip -c  > /some_folder/hda.img.gz
```

Just put right name instead of hda (it may be sda). After compression it will be much smaller.

Comment: It will also take some time.  Depending of many factor it may take a couple minutes per gig.  Possibly more time if going over USB1

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is put the old hard drive into an external enclosure and boot from it into Boot Camp. Then you can use the free [VMware Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/) to make a VM out of it.

Comment: +1 Did this a couple weeks ago and while it took a while it has worked out well.

Comment: +Thanks I thought it's paid. Can VMware Converter converter convert VMware image back to hdd?

Comment: There's free and paid. On your question, I'm not totally tracking. Do mean 1) can VMware converter take a VMware image and restore it onto a physical computer? Or do you mean 2) save it onto a different drive when converting. The answers are 1) not that I know of, but check around. or 2) Yes.